# While(true) loop в lumbda expressions

Tags: c#

Как правильно использовать `while(true)` в моем случае?
Идея такова: выводить текст с `textbox` другой программы, себе в форму. По клику все работает, но хотелось бы мониторить этот `textbox` с интервалом 1с...

```
    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hWndParent = FindWindow(null, "Test(GetLbl)");
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => FindChild(hWndParent));
        thread.Start();
        thread.IsBackground = true;
    }

    public void FindChild(IntPtr hWndParent){
        while(true){
            EnumChildWindows(hWndParent, new EnumWindowsProc(( hWnd, lParam ) => {
            if (GetParent(hWnd) != hWndParent){
            return true;
            }
            FindChild(hWnd);
                if(GetText(hWnd).StartsWith("This is my Rich")){
                    if(label1.InvokeRequired){
                        label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label1.Text = GetText(hWnd); }));
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }), IntPtr.Zero);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: стандартный WinForms-таймер чем не устраивает? и мониторьте себе с каким угодно интервалом. И на потоки заморачиваться не нужно, там из коробки все сделано грамотно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись и без отдельного потока:

```
    void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var hWndParent = FindWindow(null, "Test(GetLbl)");
        FindChild(hWndParent);
    }

    public async Task FindChild(IntPtr hWndParent) {
        while (true) {
            EnumChildWindows(hWndParent, new EnumWindowsProc((hWnd, lParam) => {
                if (GetParent(hWnd) != hWndParent) {
                    return true;
                }
                FindChild(hWnd);
                if (GetText(hWnd).StartsWith("This is my Rich")) {
                    /* поток тот же, так что Invoke() не нужен */
                    label1.Text = GetText(hWnd);
                }
                return true;
            }), IntPtr.Zero);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: работает, но подвисает окно...

Comment: Надо бы вынести поиск из цикла. Подвисать не должно.

Answer (score 0):

"подвисает окно" именно потому, что "поток тот же". В ответе @Surfin Bird попробуйте добавить .ConfigureAwait(false) к await Task.Delay(1000) - тогда после первой задержки выполнение должно уйти в другой поток. Ну и label1 выставляйте в зависимости от if(label1.InvokeRequired)
С другой стороны - а чем не годится Ваш собственный вариант, если "все работает"? Если не нравится запуск "по клику", то, вероятно, можно повесить этот код на событие открытия формы.